# Identifying the File System Root with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a basic operation where I start from a given directory, and I traverse up the filesystem until I hit the root. On Linux/Mac, the root is obviously `/` and on Windows it can be `C:\` or another drive letter of course. My question is whether or not there is a way for Node.js to identify what the root directory of the filesystem is.

Currently, I'm resorting to simply checking the last directory against `path.normalize(dir + "/../")` to see if it stops changing. Is there a `process` property/method out there? Maybe a module?

Comment: If running on Windows, which drive letter do you want? The system drive? Drive containing the running script? Drive containing another file? A hardcoded drive letter?

Comment: I would think "/" works on both platforms. For what purpose would you use it?

Comment: On Windows: Start > Run > cmd.exe. `C:\Users\Domenic > cd /`. Gets me directly to `C:\>`.

Comment: @icktoofay I'm starting based on `process.cwd()`, so based on the thread that spawns the node script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
var path = require("path");
var os = require("os");
var root = (os.platform == "win32") ? process.cwd().split(path.sep)[0] : "/"
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in Node 0.12.4 (don't know about other versions) you need to do `os.platform` is a function, so you need to do `os.platform()`

Comment: in v6.9.4 it is os.platform()

Comment: Even better, change [os.platform](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform) to [process.platform](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform), no need for `os`

Answer (score 24):

Another one, using `path.parse`.

```
const path = require('path')

const getRootDir = () => path.parse(process.cwd()).root
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special that Node.js needs to do, the answer is a simple regex:

```
/^([^\\/]*[\\/]).*/.test(process.cwd())
var root = RegExp.$1;
```

That should get the root from the CWD for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: [RegExp.$x are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties)

Comment: /^([^\\/]*[\\/]).*/.exec(process.cwd())[1]    is way easier to read

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to do this is simply to check if [`path.dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathdirnamepath) returns the same path as the input path: if it does, then it is the root.

```js
const { dirname } = require('path');

// On Linux, MacOS or other POSIX-like file-systems:
dirname("/") === "/"       // -> true
// On Windows:
dirname("C:\\") === "C:\\" // -> true
```

Here is an example output from Node.js (v14) REPL. Note that `path` will automatically resolve to `path.win32` or `path.posix` depending on your system, so you don't have to worry about platform compatability:

```
> path.posix.dirname("/") === "/"
true
> path.win32.dirname("C:\\") === "C:\\"
true
```

So if you want a utility function for it, you can do something like:

```js
const isRoot = (path) => dirname(path) === path
```

… or if you want to traverse parents until you hit the root, you can do something like:

```js
function parent(path) {
  const parentPath = dirname(path);

  return parentPath === path ? null : parentPath;
}

let path = process.cwd();

do {
  console.log(path);
} while (path = parent(path))
```